# React y Cloud Firestore Mostrar los documentos de una coleccion y de los documentos mostrar los datos de la subcoleccion

Tags: javascript, firebase, reactjs

Intento mostrar datos de una colección en los que tengo varios documentos, pero en esos documentos tengo subcolecciones y quiero mostrar la información de ellos también pero no encuentro una manera.

```
class Mapa extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('coordenadas');
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
      curIndex: undefined,
      boards: []
    };
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const boards = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { ejeX, ejeY, nombre } = doc.data();
      boards.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        ejeX,
        ejeY,
        nombre
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      boards
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.boards.map((board) => {
          board.ejeX, board.ejeY;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

No se como acceder a las subcolecciones

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. ¿podrías dar un poco más de contexto sobre tu problema? ¿a que documento/subcolecciones te refieres? ¿estás actualmente mostrando algo? ¿acaso tratas de mostrar esas subcolecciones pero no te salen? Revisa [ask] para ver cómo mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: La colección tiene varios documentos y dentro cada documento hay subcolecciones, ahora quiero mostrar todos los documentos de la colección y a la vez mostrar las subcolecciones de cada documentos no se si me explico

Comment: Pero lo que dices es prácticamente lo mismo que explicaste en la pregunta. Me refería a que des más contexto sobre cuales son esas subcolecciones que quieres mostrar, que variables son, como las accedes, cuales son sus atributos, funciones o lo que sea relevante para que se te ayude, como quieres mostrarlo, donde, que es lo que actualmente estás mostrando. Aquí nadie más que tú sabe los detalles de tu problema. Saludos